# cycling around a list indices

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list of integers, `L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and a number `x` is specified. I need to write a function such that it will take the first element of `L`, whose index is `0`, add subsequent elements until `x`, (so `j+1`, `j+2`, in our case), and return this as the first element of another list `R`, and do the same for subsequent elements. the trick is that we need to cycle around the list when `j+1` or `j+x` are `> len(L)`.

For example;

```
R = [5 (2+3), 7 (3+4), 9 (4+5), 6 (5+1), 3 (1+2)]
```

When `x < 0`, say `-2`, we go backward instead of forward. So `j-1` to `j-x`.

I wrote the following code for x>0, however I am having a trouble with indices.

```py
def decode(L, x):
    R = []

    if x > 0:
        for j in L:
            i1 = L.index(j)+1-len(L)
            i2 = L.index(j)+x-len(L)

            R[L.index(j)] = sum(L[i1:i2])+L[i2]

    return R
```

The problem happens when `i1` is negative and `i2` is `0` or positive, which returns an empty list.

Comment: Can you provide more concrete examples?  For instance what should `decode(L,3)` return and why?

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the problem statement either. What exactly does x represent? Are you just adding together the first x elements of the list?

Comment: x represents the number of elements you need to sum after the element j. So, for x = 3, and for the first element of 1, you need to sum 2+3+4 = 9, for the element 2, the three subsequent elements are 3, 4, 5 and their sum is 12, and so on. the problem is when you have part of the sequence at the end of the list and the remaining at the beginning. for example, for j = 4, the sequence you need to sum is 5 + 1 +2 = 8. so you need to cycle around the list from the beginning (1+2).  R should be [9, 12, 10, 8, 6].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use itertools functions to iterate through the values without having to bother with indexes.   The `cycle` function will automatically wrap around the list elements for you.  The `islice` function allows you to iterate from a specific offset (x).  The `accumulate` function can build totals as you go thus avoiding the need to add subscripts of the list (i.e. working from differences between cumulative sums):

```
from itertools import accumulate,cycle,islice,tee

def decode(L,x):
    S1,S2 = tee(accumulate(cycle(L)),2)     # cumulative sums
    S2    = islice(S2,x,None)               # offset end from start
    return [e-s for _,s,e in zip(L,S1,S2)]  # sub-sums are differences

L = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(decode(L,2))
[5, 7, 9, 6, 3]

print(decode(L,3))
[9, 12, 10, 8, 6]
```

For x = 2, S1 and S2 will be combined by zip() to match a start  (s) and an end (n) cumulative values with a difference corresponding to the sum of number in between:

```
L     :       1,  2,  3,  4,  5
S1 (s):       1,  3,  6, 10, 15, ...
S2 (e): 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 16, 18, ...
e-s   : ..... 5,  7,  9,  6,  3   
          ^
          first 2 of S2 skipped by islice()
```

*Note: for negative values of x, you could reverse the list or add `len(L)` to the offset of the islice, depending on what you expect the order of the output to be (i.e. would it be in reversed order or simply add preceding numbers instead of subsequent)*

[EDIT] In order to do this without libraries, you could build an actual list of cumulative values and use the same approach on a subscript of that cumulative list offset by x positions:

```
def decode(L,x):
    S = L[:1]
    S.extend(S[-1]+n for n in L[1:] + L)     # cumulative sums
    return [e-s for _,s,e in zip(L,S,S[x:])] # offset differences
```

*In order to cover all possible values of x, up to the length of the list, you need the cumulative sums to be twice as long as the input list*

If you don't mind adding the same items multiple times to get the sums, you could simply double the list and use positive indexes in sub-ranges.  The repeated content will have the same effect as a wrap around:

```
def decode(L,x):
    if x<0: return decode(L[::-1],-x)[::-1] 
    return [ sum((L*2)[i+1:i+1+x]) for i in range(len(L))]
```

*I added the negative x process as an example of how to manage it with the same (positive) logic*

Comment: thank you for the code, however, the problem must be solved without importing libraries such as itertools.

Comment: @TalalGhannam Then please say so in the question, otherwise you are wasting the time of users who provide answers (`itertools` is in Python's standard library which is an essential part of Python).

Comment: thanks @Alain T. for the codes. They are simple and work great.

Answer (score 0):

i just figure out the answer... Thanks Scott Hunter for the hint.

```
def decode(L, x):
        R = []
        
        if x > 0:
            for j in L:
                Long = L+L
                i1 = L.index(j)+1
                i2 = L.index(j)+x+1
                R.append(sum(Long[i1:i2]))
        
        elif x < 0:
            for j in L:
                x = np.abs(x)
                Long = L+L
                Long = Long[::-1]
                i1 = L.index(j)+1
                i2 = L.index(j)+x+1
                R.append(sum(Long[i1:i2]))
            R = R[::-1]   
                
        return R
```